# How do I merge together two columns from two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Hello I have the following dataframes:

```
  df = 
    x val 
    1 5 
    2 10
    5 3
```

and

```
  df1 = 
    x val 
    1 2 
    3 4
    4 8
    5 2
```

I would like to a dataframe that returns the average in the same `x`.

```
  df2 = 
    x val 
    1 3.5
    2 10
    3 4
    4 8
    5 2.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to Concatenate the dataframes then groupby 'x'.

```
df2 = pd.concat([df,df1])
df2.groupby('x').mean()
```

Produces:

```
    val
x      
1   3.5
2  10.0
3   4.0
4   8.0
5   2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

It works with two dataframes. What about if I have different realizations and I want to do other statistical analysis over the different session?
Let say I have the following data frame

```
df
   x val  session
    1 5     0
    2 10    0
    5 3     0
    1 5     1
    2 10    1
    3 4     1
    4 8     1
    5 7     1
    2 6     2
    3 4     2
    5 9     2
```

What I am doing is something like this:

```
s_un = pd.unique(df.session)
df_out = pd.Dataframe()
for in s_un:
     df_out = pd.concat([df_out,df[df.session=i]],ignore_index=True)
```

Is that correct?